# scm connection tag in Maven vs. real place of the project

Tags: java, maven, svn, maven-release-plugin

Maven uses the `<scm><connection>` tag for the SVN (or Git) path.

Up to now this information was only metadata for us -- in some projects, the information is wrong (branch has trunk scm connection) or missing.

Now we start the use the Maven release plugin, which seems to read the information from this tag. Is there a good way to check whether the content of the connection tag is actually correct? I mean, for the build we check out from a given location and that location should be the same as the one in the POM.

As we have 1800+ separate Java projects, it is hard to correct this manually (and keeping it correct after branching is another matter).

Comment: There's nothing automatic.  Developers have to set it properly.  Only a human can know what the correct answer is.

Comment: @duffymo Why? It would be great if I could tell my build server: If you check out a project from svn path X and the pom says svn path Y, fail the build. Or, alternatively, overwrite the connection tag in the pom from the build server.